# Prevent script from editing file using condition?

Tags: php

I have a script set up to download a file once or else echo a file not found message. I'm learning php so forgive my ignorance on this topic.

The script check keys in a file and then removes the key if a match is found:

```
keys = file('//keys location');
$match = false;

foreach($keys as &$one) {
    if(rtrim($one)==$key) {
        $match = true;
        $one = '';
    }
}
```

I  would like to set a condition though to NOT remove the key if the following occurance happens: 
File bytes didnt complete sending
User aborted.

The following script i found that should work if i do it right:

```
ignore_user_abort(true); // Don't end if the connection breaks

$path = //path of file

if (readfile($path) !== false && !connection_aborted()) {
// Success! Add Remove key Script

    foreach($keys as &$one) {
        if(rtrim($one)==$key) {
            $match = true;
            $one = '';
        }
    }

}
else {
// Failed! Dont remove key script here

    if ($keys !== &$one) {
        //Do Not remove key?
    }

}
```

I have queries about this code:

1. Does it actually read file bytes? How does it pickup the abort?
2. Is my script for the condition correctly implemented?